# Removing special characters and space from string

Tags: php, regex, codeigniter

I have to stored posts to database. I want to store post title as post url, so that I need to remove special characters and spaces. I have done that. Everything is working fine but when I give space at last of the string it shows hyphen at last as follows.
Ex abcd_
I just want to remove last hyphen if there is a space.
I have tried so far as follows -

```
function clean($post_name) {
               $post_name = str_replace(' ', '-', $post_name); 
               return preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $post_name);
            }
            $post_url=clean($post_name);
```

How is this possible?
Thanks.

Comment: Try to `trim()` as I showed in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this.The `trim()` function removes whitespace and other predefined characters from both sides of a string.

```
function clean($post_name) {
               $name = trim($post_name);
               $post_name = str_replace(' ', '-', $name); 
               return preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $post_name);
            }
            $post_url=clean($post_name);
```

For more http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php

Comment: @ This is exactly what I wanted. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Try to `trim()` before `str_replace()`

```
$post_name = str_replace(' ', '-', trim($post_name));
```

Answer (score 1):

To fix your problem here is my 1%

```
function clean($post_name) {
    $post_name = trim($post_name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check the last two characters of the given string. then assign the substring if its as defined. you will be able to more "defined characters" into the if block to check.

```
$len = strlen($post_name)

// check if last two characters are ' -'
if ( substr($post_name, $len -2, $len) === ' -' ) {

    // assign all but the last two characters.
    $post_name = substr($post_name, 0, $len -2);

}
```